# Comparing accuracies of Grid Search CV & Randomized Search CV with K-Fold Cross Validation?

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy, hyperparameter-tuning, gridsearchcv

Are Grid Search CV & Randomized Search CV always/necessarily supposed to give **more accurate results** after hyperparameter tuning as compared to K-Fold Cross Validation?

Comment: Grid Search CV & Randomized Search CV are hyperparameter tuning strategies that use K-Fold Cross Validation internally to evaluate each hyperparameter configuration.

Is this the intended question: does hyperparameter tuning consistently provide better model accuracy than not having hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I first tried K Fold CV on my ML model, then Grid Search. My accuracy turned out to be slightly higher for K Fold though Grid & Radom Searches are expected to do better. So my doubt is, is it possible for K Fold to perform better than Grid Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above, " though Grid & Radom Searches are **expected** to do better." They are **EXPECTED** to perform better but it is not a given that in each and every case they will outperform K Fold CV. Sometimes K FoldCV can outperform Grid or Random SearchCV.